# Adding Schema prefix to Nhibernate Table naming convention

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using a Multitenant Application for various companies . I am yet to get success with this . But what my scenario is I have a single sql server database with tablesets with different companies (tenants).

So what I want to do is add a convention for table which would access the table with its schema prefix in the table as per multitenant application concept . I am not using database per tenant but using schema per tenant . Database file is a single file .

What I want to do is my tables are like this `Sachin Sales & Service Pvt Ltd$Web User Setup Header`. so I want when the table queries would be generated they should add prefix `Sachin Sales & Service Pvt Ltd` on fly before querying . The prefix may change on requirement . Its not static . So I thought of overriding IClassConvention which by default looks like this

```
 public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Table( instance.EntityType.Name);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway I can pass another parameter like `string schemaname` like this to generate the desired tablename with schema prefix ? My idea is to do something like this :

```
public class TableNameConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance, string schemaname )
    {
        instance.Table(schemaname + instance.EntityType.Name);
    }
}
```

If so my questions are here like this . If i am able to achieve the point mentioned above will it solve my schema per tenant problem ? 
And second even if the above doesnt give any errors while compiling (technically shouldnt) how am I supposed to pass schemaname into that override ? I mean how should I call since This is just a convention and I cannot manipulate it on fly (which I actually want to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the schema use for all tables when configuring nhibernate, e.g.

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.DefaultSchema(sometenantsSchema))
```

Comment: Wil that add a prefix to the table naming while quering ?

Comment: this will add the schema prefix to all mappings (through the Configuration property "default_schema", see NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.DefaultSchema). Queries are generated from the mappings